# Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'greenday_head' not found or invalid function name

Tags: functions, hooks, code

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'greenday_head' not found or invalid function name in /home/xnvrtebr/public_html/Blog/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 286
```

I have had this error for a while but didn't notice it because it's hidden on a black background.

I have looked up the code for class-wp-hook.php and here is line 286:

```
$value = call_user_func_array( $the_['function'], $args );
```

I am using an old wordpress theme, so there is no longer any support. I can't even find it online anymore. I'm not really sure what I'm doing. Help!

What code do I need to insert and where?

Comment: It just mean function with name `greenday_head` does not exists in you theme, while it is called on some action/filter. Search for `greenday_head` in your theme files (or plugin if it's coming from some plugin).

Comment: This is impossible to answer without some access to the actual code, but if everything is functioning well, you can just add such a function that does nothing just to silence the error.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by creating in the themes functions.php a function like this

```
public function greenday_head($args) {
  return $args
}
```

It may be that $args are never passed in but it seems likely they are. If you want to try to find out what this is doing then you can add:

```
public function greenday_head($args) {
  echo '<pre>' . var_export($args, true) . '</pre>';
  echo '<pre>' . var_dump(debug_backtrace()) . '</pre>';
  return $args
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much but I managed to solve the issue after reverting to the default functions.php code/file